# Re-upload a file to SharePoint Document Library SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I am working in SP 2013 On-premise. I am trying to re-upload documents from a folder in my local machine to my document Library. The code works fine. However, on downloading the document, I see no change in the document content even though the version gets updated (this maybe because I am also updating a field).

I am using CSOM **SaveBinaryDirect** method. This is my code :

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, path, stream, true);
var uploadedfile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(path);
context.Load(uploadedfile);
context.ExecuteQuery();

if(uploadedfile.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
{
     uploadedfile.CheckOut();
}

context.ExecuteQuery();
var listitem = uploadedfile.ListItemAllFields;
listitem["column"] = "Value";
listitem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
listitem.File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please try to check-out the file before replacing its content and check-in after replacing its content and properties.

Comment: Hi Divya thanks for replying, I did try that, I first loaded the uploaded file and then used the SaveBinaryDirect method. However there was no change in the document content.

Comment: I mean checked out the file first and then tried saving it but there was no change